# PHP not retrieving unicode characters from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to retrieve a string from MySQL that contains japanese characters. I'm using

`$handle =  new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER . ";charset=utf8", USERNAME, PASSWORD);`

to connect to the database, and i can store the string just fine, using the same method to connect. It shows up like this

[image: pic #1]

But when i retrieve it using the same method to print it to a web page it'll just show ? instead of the characters. Like this http://puu.sh/bd1fX.png. The characters after "Name" are hardcoded here for testing purposes.

[image: pic #2]

Here's the function i'm using to connect and retrieve data http://pastebin.com/7jj7MLjd

If anyone has any suggestions as to why i can't get the characters back from the databse, that'd be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Is your html file set to support utf-8 characters?
I mean `<meta charset="utf-8">` is there in `<head>` section?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your html file is set to support `utf-8` characters?

I mean `<meta charset="utf-8">` is there in `<head>` section?

Comment: The thing is that when the string is returned from the function the letters are already ??? before they're printed to the html form. But i also do have meta charset defined already.